# How can I open an elevated tab?

Tags: windows-terminal

As the title says. How can I open up a new **elevated tab** in the new windows terminal without having to open an entire new window? I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496779/opening-up-windows-terminal-with-elevated-privileges-from-within-windows-termin). However it only talks about opening up a new elevated window in a comfortable way.

[image]

Comment: It can be done using [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently open an elevated tab in a non-elevated Terminal instance as this could expose the user/processes to various integrity level vulnerabilities.

However, you CAN launch a separate elevated Terminal instance just as you would any other Windows app - right clicking the Icon in your taskbar or start menu, and then right clicking the "Windows Terminal" entry in the pop-up context menu:

[image: Launch an elevated Terminal instance]

Alternatively, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking the Terminal icon in your taskbar or start menu.

> ⚠️ Note: It is highly recommended that you only run an elevated application long enough to complete a given task that requires elevation, and then close that application and continue running a non-elevated instance. This will help ensure that you do not unnecessarily expose yourself, your data, and your systems to potential violation.