# Setting up Visual Studio Code to run models from Hugging Face

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to import models from hugging face and use them in Visual Studio Code.
I installed transformers, tensorflow, and torch.
I have tried looking at multiple tutorials online but have found nothing.
I am trying to run the following code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
result = classifier("I hate it when I'm sitting under a tree and an apple hits my head.")
print(result)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
No model was supplied, defaulted to distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english and revision af0f99b (https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence\transformers\Workshops\workshop_3.py", line 4, in <module>
    classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence\transformers\src\transformers\pipelines\__init__.py", line 702, in pipeline
    framework, model = infer_framework_load_model(
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence\transformers\src\transformers\pipelines\base.py", line 266, in infer_framework_load_model
    raise ValueError(f"Could not load model {model} with any of the following classes: {class_tuple}.")
ValueError: Could not load model distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_auto.AutoModelForSequenceClassification'>, <class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification'>, <class 'transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_distilbert.DistilBertForSequenceClassification'>, <class 'transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert.TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification'>).
```

I have already searched online for ways to set up transformers to use in Visual Studio Code but nothing is helping.

Do you know how to fix this error, or if someone knows how to successfully use models from Hugging Face into my code, it would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little less about Hugging Face itself and likely more about installation and the installation steps you took (and potentially your program's access to the cache file where the models are automatically downloaded to.).

From what I am seeing either:
1/ your program is unable to access the model
2/ your program is throwing specific value errors in a bit of an edge case

If 1/ Take a look here: [https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#cache-setup][1]

Notice that it the docs walks through where the pre-trained models are downloaded. Check that it was downloaded here: `C:\Users\username\.cache\huggingface\hub` (of course with your own username on your computer instead.  Check in the cache location to make sure it was downloaded? (You can check in the cache locations mentioned.)

Second, if for some reason, there is an issue with downloading, you can try downloading manually and doing it via offline mode (this is more to get it up and running): https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode

Third, if it is downloaded, do you have the right permissions to access the .cache? (Try running your program (if it is a program that you trust) on Windows Terminal as an administrator.). Various ways - find one that you're comfortable with, here are a couple hints from Stackoverflow/StackExchange: [Opening up Windows Terminal with elevated privileges, from within Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496779/opening-up-windows-terminal-with-elevated-privileges-from-within-windows-termin) or this: https://superuser.com/questions/1560049/open-windows-terminal-as-admin-with-winr

If 2/ I have seen people bring up very specific issues on not finding specific values (not the same as yours but similar) and the issue was solved by installing PyTorch because some models only exist as PyTorch models.  You can see the full response from @YokoHono here: [Transformers model from Hugging-Face throws error that specific classes couldn t be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622895/transformers-model-from-hugging-face-throws-error-that-specific-classes-couldn-t)